# How to resolve the no exported member error in Angular?

Tags: angular

Here is my actual error:

```
Failed to compile.
C:/Examples/my-app/src/app/lake.service.ts (4,10): Module '"C:/Examples/my-app/src/app/lake-info"' has no exported member 'LAKES'.
```

Here is the code of `lake-info`:

```
import { Lake } from './lake';

export const LAKES: Lake[] = [
  { name: 'Manitoba'},
  { name: 'Khanka'}
];
```

Here is the code for `lake.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Lake } from './lake';
import { LAKES } from './lake-info';

@Injectable()
export class LakeService {
  getLakes(): Lake[] {
    return LAKES;
  }
}
```

Here is the code for `lake.ts`:

```
export class Lake {
  name: string;
}
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#getheroes-in-the-appcomponent) on the Angular website. My `lake-info` file is based on [this file](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#move-the-mock-hero-data).

Let me know if I need to add more details.

Comment: how do you import the Lakes ?

Comment: share your lake.service.ts!

Comment: @GauravSrivastava I am adding the code. :)

Comment: @VineetSharma still getting the error after adding lake.ts?

Comment: @GauravSrivastava Yes. I am getting the same error this time too. :)

Answer (score 1):

define a file in **lake.ts** in same folder and add this code:

```
export class Lake {
  constructor(public id = 0, public name = '') { }
  clone() { return new Lake(this.id, this.name); }
}
```

You can customize this according to your requirement.

Comment: Is the tutorial on the Angular website wrong? They don't seem to have the corresponding code in their file. :)

I am also adding the code for `lake.ts` in my question for reference.

Comment: @VineetSharma yes it seems they missed the hero.ts code on the tutorial

Comment: @VineetSharma you should not be getting this error after adding lake.ts i tested it locally. please recompile the code.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code in plnkr and that's ok.

https://plnkr.co/edit/kW6B5VSxcmrwQiyQshQT?p=preview

Could you move your project code into plnkr and share to me?

Maybe be the reason of your compile error is the import order (I'm not sure, just guess).

Try drag a topology graph of file import and check if is a cycle in the graph.

In the case of my plnkr the graph is like below and there is no cycle (Cycle import is not unallowed but it's easy to cause problem):

```
lake.ts <- lake-info.ts
^  ^         ^ ^
|  |         | |
| lake.service |
|      ^       |
|      |       |
app.component.ts
```